# 英語が残っている：質問のクローズ＞オフトピックの理由

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

> - This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network
> - Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)

[Transifexに入れることができないそうなので](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40286061)、訳がまとまったらそれを反映してもらおうと思います。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - この質問は Stack Exchange ネットワークの他のサイト（もしくはメタ）に移動すべきです
> - その他（理由をコメントで説明します）

という翻訳でいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 上記文言でサイトに反映されているようです。