# 英語が残っている: クローズ理由の「その他」欄

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

メタサイトで質問の「閉じる」を押したあと、オフトピックを理由として選び、詳細な理由を「その他（理由をコメントで説明します）」として投稿しようとすると、デフォルトで入っているコメント雛形が英語のままになっています。

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because

[image: コメント雛形に英語が残っている部分のスクリーンショットです。]

現状 Traducir にはこの部分の string が収録されていないようです。[過去の投稿](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1927/19110)を参考にすると、仕組み的に Traducir/Transifex へ収録できないのかもしれません。以下のように訳したいのですが、権限を持っている方に反映をお願いしたいです。

> オフトピックとしてこの質問へクローズ票を入れます。なぜなら

---

ついでに、その上に書かれている

> この質問は、Stack Overflow in Japanese or the software that powers the Stack Exchange networkについてヘルプ センターで定義されている範囲から外れているようです。

というのも何だかおかしいので直せるようであれば直したいです。以下の訳でいかがでしょうか。

> この質問は、Stack Exchange ネットワークを支えるソフトウェアやスタック・オーバーフローについて、ヘルプセンターで定義されている範囲から外れているようです。

また、この「ヘルプセンター」は現状だと https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help へリンクしていますが、メインサイト側の文章では https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic へリンクしているので、どちらへのリンクが正しいのか原文を確認し、異なっていたら整えたいです (私は本家 Stack Overflow の信用度が貯まっていないので見ることができません)。

Comment: 細かい指摘になりますが、「スタック・オーバーフローに **ついて** 」より「スタック・オーバーフローに **おいて** 」の方が個人的にはしっくりきます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traducir に string がございましたm(_ _)m。
[image]

以下は反映されております。
[image]